# Как найти аналогичную модель touchpad для замены

Tags: железо, тач

Помогите найти аналогичную модель тачпада.
На ноутбуке произошло короткое замыкание. Детальку поменял мастер, всё работает... а вот тачпад умер. В диспетчере устройств и вообще в устройствах его нет. Сказал, что нужно его менять, но на какой? С двумя шлейфами не нахожу в поиске или по каким параметрам мне нужно подобрать его для своей машинки?)
Модель ноутбука Acer Spin 3.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Было бы неплохо - привести точную модель ноута.

Comment: @donRumata Acer Spin 3 SP313-51N

Comment: Ну ебэй говорит, что вот эта штука должна подойти: https://www.ebay.com/itm/255414069983

Comment: @donRumata Ух ты, спасибо!!! Пойду пробовать заказать) Маленький шлейф для входа по отпечатку, он не обязателен, а так один в один.)